# Splide svelte doesn't update based on dynamic options properly

Tags: dynamic, svelte, splidejs

I'm trying to make the [Splide](https://splidejs.com/integration/svelte-splide/) carousel responsive by changing the `perPage` prop based on screen size, but it works only when `perPage` increases, decreasing the screen size will end up in very strange behavior:

```
<script>
      let innerWidth
      $: tileNumber = innerWidth > 900 ? 2 : 1
      $: carouselOptions = {
        gap: '1rem',
        padding: '10rem',
        focus: 0,
        perPage: tileNumber,
        perMove: 1,
        arrows: false,
        pagination: false,
      }
</script>
<svelte:window bind:innerWidth />
<p>{tileNumber}</p>

<Splide aria-label={title} bind:options={carouselOptions}>
    {#each items as item}
      <SplideSlide>
        <div class="w-full h-40 {bgClass}">{item.title}</div>
      </SplideSlide>
    {/each}
  </Splide>
```

So if the page starts with small screen, dragging the screen to wider position will change `tileNumber` to 2, and `perPage` updates properly, but once it is 2, when `tileNumber` becomes 1, carousel still shows 2 main items. When I make the screen even smaller or to mobile size screen, carousel shows 3 main items, I have no idea where 3 comes from.

[image]
[image]